# Ler valores de diversas DIVs e realizar o cálculo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, soma

Estou tentando fazer uma função que leia os dados da div `<div class="rowtabela">` e os itens que constam nela nas divs `<div class="item v_...">`

Criei o formulário abaixo, onde exibe abaixo os valores lançados:

```
<div class="row" id="dados-volumetria">
    <div class="col-lg-2 text-label">                   
        <label>Volumes</label>                  
        <input type="number" class="form-control gridresponsivo cubagem_Q" id="quantidade" name="quantidade" maxlength="9"  autocomplete="off"  placeholder="Apenas números"/>  
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 text-label">                   
        <label>Altura</label>                   
        <input class="form-control gridresponsivo cubagem_A" id="altura" name="altura"   autocomplete="off"  /> 
    </div>      
    <div class="col-lg-2 text-label">               
        <label>Largura</label>                  
        <input class="form-control gridresponsivo cubagem_L" id="largura" name="largura"   autocomplete="off"  />   
    </div>  
    <div class="col-lg-2 text-label">               
        <label>Profundidade</label>                 
        <input class="form-control gridresponsivo cubagem_P" id="profundidade" name="profundidade"   autocomplete="off"  /> 
    </div>  
    <div class="col-lg-2 text-label">               
        <label>Peso</label>                 
        <input class="form-control gridresponsivo cubagem_K" id="peso" name="peso"   autocomplete="off"  /> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 text-label">
        <label>&nbsp;</label>                               
        <input type="button"  class="form-control gridresponsivo txt-valor-nf btn btn-success btn-sm" id="addVolume"  value="Adicionar" onclick="adicionar()"  />
    </div>                          
</div>                  
<div class="adicionados" id="tabela">
    <div class="rowtabela">
        <div class="item v_volumes">
            <b>Volumes</b>
        </div>
        <div class="item v_altura">
            <b>Altura</b>
        </div>  
        <div class="item v_largura">
            <b>Largura</b>
        </div>  
        <div class="item v_profundidade">
            <b>Profundidade</b>
        </div>  
        <div class="item v_peso">
            <b>Peso</b>
        </div>                              
        <div class="item">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

E o JS abaixo:

```
function adicionar(){                         
    var tabela = document.getElementById('tabela');
    var qtd = document.getElementById("quantidade").value;
    var ta = document.getElementById("altura").value;
    var tl = document.getElementById("largura").value;
    var tp = document.getElementById("profundidade").value;
    var tk = document.getElementById("peso").value;


    var vol_id = document.body.querySelectorAll(".rowtabela").length;

    var novo_item = '<div class="rowtabela" id="'+vol_id+'">'
    +'<div class="item v_volumes dv_volumes">'+qtd+'</div>'
    +'<div class="item v_altura">'+ta+'</div>'
    +'<div class="item v_largura">'+tl+'</div>'
    +'<div class="item v_profundidade">'+tp+'</div>'
    +'<div class="item v_peso">'+tk+'</div>'
    +'<div class="botao">'
    +'<input type="button"  class="form-control gridresponsivo txt-valor-nf btn btn-danger btn-sm" value="X" onclick="remover(this)" />'
    +'</div></div>';

    tabela.innerHTML += novo_item;

    calcula_cubagem_volumes();
}

function remover(e){
    e.parentNode.parentNode.outerHTML = '';

    calcula_cubagem_volumes();
}

function calcula_cubagem_volumes(){
    //para cada linha incluída eu preciso calular
    //preciso retornar a cubagem: (altura * largura * profundidade) * volumes
    //preciso retornar volumes * peso
    //e depois retornar o a soma dos volumes
}
```

Após preencher os valores de volumes, peso, altura, largura e profundidade e clicar em Adicionar os dados são exibidos em na div `rowtabela`. Eles podem ser 1 ou muitos itens. E podem ser excluídos através do botão "X". Porém com a exclusão, o id da div `rowtabela` fica inconclusivo.

O que eu gostaria era de retornar os valores da div `rowtabela` em javascript e realizar o calculo de cubagem que seria (altura * largura * profundidade) * volumes, o valor do peso * volumes, para cada linha e retornar no final a soma das cubagens, pesos e volumes.

Não preciso do cálculo feito, só a forma para ler esses valores linha a linha.

Havia tentado dessa forma, porém ele concatena todos os valores na única variável:

```
$.each($('.rowtabela'), function(index, value) {
    console.log(index + ':' + $(value).text());
});
```

Fiz o fiddle abaixo, referente ao meu código.

https://jsfiddle.net/3qn8mg1k/

Answer (score 0):

Podemos fazer loop pelos descendentes de cada fila. Na primeira fila obtemos os nomes das colunas. Coloca-se os valores num objeto e faz-se os cálculos.

```
function calcula_cubagem_volumes(){
    //para cada linha incluída eu preciso calular
    //preciso retornar a cubagem: (altura * largura * profundidade) * volumes
    //preciso retornar volumes * peso
    //e depois retornar o a soma dos volumes
    var colunas = [];
    var volumes_total = 0;
    var cubagem_total = 0;
    var peso_total = 0;
    $.each($('.rowtabela'), function(index, value) {


      if (index == 0) {
        $.each($(this).children(), function(i2, val2) {
          colunas.push($(val2).text().trim())
        });
      }
      else {
        var fila = {};
        $.each($(this).children(), function(i2, val2) {
          if (i2 < 5) {
            fila[colunas[i2]] = Number($(val2).text());
            console.log(colunas[i2] + ": " + $(val2).text());
          }
        });
        var cubagem = fila["Volumes"] * (fila["Altura"] * fila["Largura"] * fila["Profundidade"]);
        var peso = fila["Volumes"] * fila["Peso"];

        console.log("Cubagem da fila: " + cubagem);
        console.log("Peso da fila: " + peso);

        volumes_total += fila["Volumes"];
        cubagem_total += cubagem;
        peso_total += peso;
      }
    });

    console.log("Volumes total: " + volumes_total);
    console.log("Cubagem total: " + cubagem_total);
    console.log("Peso total: " + peso_total);

    $("#volumes").val(volumes_total);
    $("#cubagem").val(cubagem_total);
    $("#peso_total").val(peso_total);
 }
```